# Grouping ActiveRecord objects in a Facebook-wall-like way

Tags: ruby-on-rails

You have an activity stream, similar to Facebook's Wall, with multiple types of records (statuses, updates, announcements, etc) streaming into them. You want to group similar types of records with different CSS.

The grouping can be by object owner (i.e. group the objects owned by "John" even if they are not all seqential, because "John" had 5 out of the last 7 posts), or they can be by date (i.e. group last 7 records because they all came in within 1 minute).

The best way I know how to do this is to parse the returned list of objects as we load them in the view, but that seems ugly. Is there a more elegant solution? Something more like the has_activity gem, but that can do more than just group by a specific time?

Looking more for examples and concepts than a solution, but a solution's good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desire was to do this without a giant, explicit method, and to take advantage of functional programming methods. [Matt Youell](https://github.com/built) sent me a simple way to accomplish grouping items that have arrived within one minute using inject.

```
def group?(current, last)
  current.created_at - last.created_at < 1.minute
end

recent_statuses.inject([]) { |results, status|
  next results << [status] if results.empty? # Can't compare first item.
  results << group?(status, results.last.last) ? stat : [stat]
}
```

This would result in an array of status messages and arrays of status messages, e.g.

```
[<#Status>, <#Status>, [<#Status>, <#Status>], <#Status>, [#<Status>, <#Status>], <#Status>]
```

And would allow you to parse this list with something like:

```
results.each do |result|
  if result.class == Status
    # format a single entry
  else result.class == Array
    # Enter the grouped formatting
  end
end
```

This, of course, could be expanded in many ways, including putting multiple logical groupings into group?(). Conceptually, it's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the parsing in a helper, it wouldn't be ugly:)

Comment: That's true. I was going to do it in the controller, but keeping it out of there would be best. Still, it's more a question of the methodology of parsing, collecting, organizing that information elegantly. I was looking for best practice, but there might not be one. I guess I'll just whack at it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what your inputs and outputs are (I'm just a simple Facebook user).

I assume you have a list of items in an array. Each item has some kind of type.

1. Can you place a name for the type in the CSS class of the block for each item? Let the browser sort it out through some class on the list - container ("owners-only").
2. Use Enumerable#group_by, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by